# How to get flow output from non flow fuction

Tags: list, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine, kotlin-flow

I want flow output (return type `Flow<T>`) from a non-flow function (return type`T`).

```kotlin
fun getTotalFiles(): Int 
// Say, This is a library function it'll return the number of files (Int) in that folder at that specific moment.

//And,
fun getAllFiles(): List<File> 
// Say, This is a library function it'll return all the files (List<File>) in that folder.
```

*The files in that folder can and will change in the future.*

Now, I want to constantly observe the output, so how do I implement it?

```kotlin
fun getFlowOfTotalFiles(): Flow<Int> =
// A wrapper function that converts the library function return type to an observable flow, Flow<Int>

//And,
fun getFlowOfAllFiles(): Flow<List<File>> =
// A wrapper function that converts the library function return type to an observable flow, Flow<List<File>>
```

Comment: Do you want a specific time interval to repeatedly request the updated value from the library? Or does the library provide some way to subscribe to changes with a listener? Second way is obviously much better, but we'd have to know what the library is. The first way is hacky, and when you say "constantly" that implies constant churn to keep repeatedly checking.

Comment: @Tenfour04 The library does not provide any subscribable method. Currently, I'm looking at `PackageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA)`

But in the future, I'll make a function that'll use the bash `ls` command to get all file lists and then warp it to be a flow, so I could use some advice here as well.

Comment: @Tenfour04 If you know any kotlin library that provides constant folder observation please suggest one. 

BTW, the library functions that provide flow also repeatedly runs check under the hood, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need an infinite loop inside a flow builder, something like the following:

```
fun getFlowOfTotalFiles(): Flow<Int> = flow {
    while (true) {
        emit(getTotalFiles())
        // delays for 5 sec before next request and 
        // terminates the infinite cycle when a coroutine, 
        // that collects this Flow, is canceled
        delay(5000) 
    }
}

fun getAllFilesFlow(): Flow<List<File>> = flow {
    while (true) {
        emit(getAllFiles())
        delay(5000)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks again, bro <3. Tested and working as expected.

Comment: It seems a bit hacky but it works. Also, should I not only emit if it's different from the previous emit, or does it not matter?

Comment: Well, if you want that collectors of the Flow would receive data only when it has been changed, then you can add a comparison between the previous emitted data and current, and emit it if it changed.

Comment: Or just tag it with `.distinctUntilChanged()`. For example, `= flow { /*the code above*/ }.distinctUntilChanged()`

Answer (score 3):

For specifically monitoring a directory for files, you can use WatchService and convert it to a flow with the `flow` builder. Something like this:

```
fun getDirectoryMonitorFlow(directory: String) = flow {
    FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService().use { watchService ->
        while (true) {
            val watchKey = Path.of(directory).register(watchService, ENTRY_CREATE, ENTRY_DELETE, ENTRY_MODIFY)
            if (watchKey.pollEvents().isNotEmpty()) {
                emit(Unit)
            }
            yield() // give flow opportunity to be cancelled.
            if (!watchKey.reset()) {
                println("Directory became unreadable. Finishing flow.")
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
    .catch { println("Exception while monitoring directory.") }
    .flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)
```

And then your class might look like:

```
fun getFlowOfTotalFiles(): Flow<Int> = getFlowOfAllFiles()
    .map { it.size }
    .distinctUntilChanged()

fun getFlowOfAllFiles(): Flow<List<File>> = flow {
    emit(Unit) // so current state is always emitted
    emitAll(getDirectoryMonitorFlow(directory))
}
    .map {
        File(directory).listFiles()?.toList().orEmpty()
    }
    .flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)
    .distinctUntilChanged()
```

Although you might consider making the first flow a private SharedFlow so you aren't running multiple WatchServices to monitor the same directory concurrently.