# How to transform Flow<List<Flow<List<T>>>> to Flow<List<List<T>>>?

Tags: list, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine, kotlin-flow

Consider the following,

```kotlin
val tabs: MutableStateFlow<List<Path>> = getFlowPaths() // user defined

//A function Path.contents(glob: String = "*"): Flow<List<Path>>

val tabsFlow: Flow<List<Flow<List<Path>>>> = tabs.transformLatest {
        emit(it.map { path ->
            path.contents()
        })
    }
//But I want tabsFlow to be Flow<List<List<Path>>>, is it possible to get it?
```

What I'm expecting,
Only a *single* Flow wrapped outside the whole thing rather than having more flow inside (change in content of inside flow should just simply change the content of outside flow).

Comment: What does the `contents()` function look like?

Comment: Probably you just need to change `emit` to `emitAll`.

Comment: @Tenfour04 it's just a variation from you previous answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/74032555/13519865
https://codefile.io/f/UZGkqO9M7S4NBcf8yV6S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible way to do this:

```
    val tabsFlow: Flow<List<List<Path>>> = tabs.flatMapLatest { paths ->
        combine(paths.map { path ->
            path.contents()
        }) { it.toList() }
    }
```

or

```
    val contentsFlows: List<Flow<List<Path>>> = tabs.value.map { path ->
        path.contents()
    }

    val res: Flow<List<List<Path>>> = combine(contentsFlows) { contents ->
        contents.toList()
    }
```

Comment: Hi, your answer works, thanks for sharing it! But can you please explain step by step what's happening here?